# PageView rebuilding while animateToPage is in progress

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-pageview

I'm creating a social media feed where each post is an image of a different size. The user can swipe right to like, left to dislike, up to skip to the next post, or down to go back. To do that, I'm using a Dismissible widget within a PageView, where each page contains a post/image. I used "animateToPage" in the Dismissible to automatically animate to the next page once the user swipes right or left.

**The problem is that when the PageView animates to the next page, the image that was dismissed suddenly reappears on the previous page while the animation is happening.** I want it to reappear only if the user swipes down to go back to the previous post, but not while the PageView is animating.

[Here's a video showing what is going wrong](https://youtu.be/Db1PxuPCG5Y)

[And here's an animation showing what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPAuO.gif)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin{
  int pageIndex = 0;

  PageController _pageController = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

List images = [
  'assets/1.jpg', 'assets/2.jpg', 'assets/3.jpg', 'assets/4.jpg', 'assets/5.jpg',
];

return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(250, 250, 250, 1),
    body: LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) => PageView.builder(
          controller: _pageController,
          itemCount: 5,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return images.map((image) => Dismissible(
              onResize: () {
                setState(() {
                  _pageController.animateToPage(index+1, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.ease);
                });
              },
              onDismissed: (direction) {},
              key: UniqueKey(),
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 100),
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Image(
                          image: AssetImage(image)
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ))
                .toList()[index];
          }
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
  }
}
```

I assume this is happening because PageView is rebuilding the other pages while the animation is in progress. I'm still a beginner in Flutter and wasn't able to find a solution. Any ideas of how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime `setState` is called, the widget is redrawn. Try to put your animated code outside of `setState` method.

[Documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)